# download local files using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, download

I need to download files stored in a local folder using jQuery, by clicking on the filename. My code is as follows:

```
$("#divDato_Ficheros_pestana_gestion").html("");
    if (datos.dtAdjuntos != undefined && datos.dtAdjuntos[0] != null && datos.dtAdjuntos.length > 0) {
        var adjuntos = "";
        for (var index = 0; index < datos.dtAdjuntos.length; index++) {
            var nombreFichero = datos.dtAdjuntos[index].nombreFichero;
            var nombreFicheroServer = datos.dtAdjuntos[index].nombreFicheroServer;
            adjuntos = adjuntos + "<span id='aAbrirArchivo' style='cursor: pointer;' srvName='" + nombreFicheroServer + "'>" + nombreFichero + "</span><br />";

        }
        if (adjuntos != "")
            $("#divDato_Ficheros_pestana_gestion").html(adjuntos);
    }

$("#aAbrirArchivo").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.download = $(this).attr("srvName");
        link.href = $("#CPHFiltros_hRutaFicherosAdjuntosGestion").val();
        link.click();
        console.log(e);
        console.log(link);
});
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "download local files"?  How specifically does your code fail?

Comment: Clicking on the browser does not download the file

Comment: @JeisonTorres: Then what *does* it do?  What is the HTML you're clicking on?  If the click event is executing JavaScript code, what happens when you debug that code?